# PCM sound level resets in Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pcm

I am using `Ubuntu 8.04` and seeing that `PCM` volume above 75% results in very poor sound quality. So, I brought it down.

But the problem is, after every reboot it resets to 100%. How can I save the PCM sound level such that it does not resets on reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googled and found [this](http://embraceubuntu.com/2007/03/20/saving-sound-volume-levels-across-reboots/) blog post helpful:

In short:

1. Set the volume as per your requirements
2. From terminal execute: `sudo alsactl store`

Worked for me!